# Correct way to change WIndow Size before showing

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have project moved from XE7, in OnCreate of the child form I'm change size of window, this form have Position := MainFormCenter.

Now with Berlin I have Left = 0 and Top = 0 after showing this child form. If window size is not changed in OnCreate, than this child form created correctly and it is centered over Main Form.

How I should change form size during initialization now with Delphi Berlin and not lost form position settings?

Form position changed here to TFormPosition.Designed:

```
unit FMX.Forms

procedure TCommonCustomForm.Show;
var
  LPosition: TFormPosition;
...
begin
...
          // If you changed the original coordinates or size
          if TBoundChange.Location in FBoundChanges then
          begin
            if LPosition = TFormPosition.Default then
              LPosition := TFormPosition.DefaultSizeOnly
            else if LPosition in [TFormPosition.DefaultPosOnly, TFormPosition.ScreenCenter, TFormPosition.DesktopCenter,
              TFormPosition.MainFormCenter, TFormPosition.OwnerFormCenter] then
              LPosition := TFormPosition.Designed; // Changed here to Default
          end;
...
end;
```

**Update:**

One way which I found - change size from OnShow method of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other answers - one way to fix this is changing form size in OnShow method of the form